# terraform: building account: could not acquire access token to parse claims

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, azure-rm

In portal.azure.com, i set up a new app registration for terraform and creates a certificate & secret.  the app has the 'Cloud Application Administrator' role.  I am attempting to use this to run my terraform script.

I have the following terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.53.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
}
provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
  use_cli = true
}
```

then i do a `terraform plan`, i am getting

```
│ Error: building account: could not acquire access token to parse claims: clientCredentialsToken: cannot request token: Post "https://login.microsoftonline.com/8e7e5486-6e11-48bf-9cca-ef5fd4205af3/oauth2/v2.0/token": POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/8e7e5486-6e11-48bf-9cca-ef5fd4205af3/oauth2/v2.0/token giving up after 5 attempt(s): Post "https://login.microsoftonline.com/8e7e5486-6e11-48bf-9cca-ef5fd4205af3/oauth2/v2.0/token": dial tcp: lookup login.microsoftonline.com on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on providers.tf line 13, in provider "azurerm":
│   13: provider "azurerm" {
```

I am not sure what the issue is here.  I am running this is VSCode in a devcontainer (my dev environment is dockerized).

Comment: To ensure your Docker container utilizes a reliable DNS server, add "--dns=8.8.8.8" to your Docker run command or include dns: ["8.8.8.8"] in your Docker Compose file. Additionally, verify and modify your firewall or security group settings to permit DNS queries on UDP/TCP port 53. @mike01010

Comment: @VinayB i have that dns entry in my docker compose.   If i can hit the outside world, such as google.com from my container, does it not mean my dns queries are fine?

Comment: Indeed, if you're able to access google.com from within your container, this generally indicates that DNS resolution is functioning. The problem may be specific to Azure endpoints or temporary network glitches. It's advisable to check the Azure service status and attempt again after a short wait. @mike01010

Comment: it does seem like it was temporary. i am past that error.  but it seems now the 'terraform' app registration i created does not have permission to do much despite me assigning the 'Cloud Application Administrator' role.  that does not seem to allow much provisioning via terraform/azurem/azapi. i will open a separte question for that..

Answer (score 1):

> terraform: building account: could not acquire access token to parse claims is caused due to temporary network issue.

As you mentioned it seems you surpassed the error this might be because of temporary network issue which can also identifies by changing your container's networking mode.

Docker defaults to a bridged network but switching to host networking (by adding `--network="host"` to your `docker run` command) may resolve DNS resolution problems, though it may also affect the container's isolation.

This issue often stems from DNS configuration problems within the Docker container where your development environment and Terraform are running, and it's **`temporary`**.

Additionally, the error suggests that your retry logic is giving up after 5 attempts. You may need to verify that your Docker container has a stable internet connection before executing Terraform commands.

Sometimes Docker container may not have proper DNS settings. By default, Docker attempts to use the DNS settings of the host machine, but network issues or DNS blocking can interfere with this process. You can explicitly set DNS servers for Docker containers by modifying the Docker daemon configuration or using the `--dns` flag with `docker run`.

And the issue mentioned in the comment was required **`reader`** access to your container registry.  **`Cloud Application Administrator`** alone won't workout in your case.

[image]

**`Reference:`**

[Docker-networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

[Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=delegate-condition)

Comment: What i am confused about here is - ok i can add the Reader role to the resource group. But how do i limit it such that only my user or the app i registered are allowed those actions?  i can see a way to link an "App" to that role for a particular resource

Comment: Assign the Reader role to the resource group specifically for your user or the registered application by utilizing role-based access control (RBAC) policies and ensure to target only those specific entities. @mike01010